# Looking for works pointing to Christianity as an alternative to human sacrifice

Tags: early-church, reference-request, sacrifice

I'm curious if there is any significant scholarly research or works  regarding a theory that a key driver of the spread of Christianity was to replace human and animal sacrifice from religious practice?

Comment: This is the expression of an opinion without any substantiation or quoted research.

Comment: What "spread of abrahamic religion"? I don't see a spread of abrahamic religion at all pre-christianity.

Comment: @nigel reads like a reference request to me.  user11547, I see where you're going with the question and it looks like you're looking to start a conversation.  This, being a Q&A site, not a Christian discussion forum is a better place to look for concrete answers than to engage in that kind of inquiry.  But you can ask for a Bibliography on the subject to go do your own research and come back here with specific questions.

Comment: The question refers to "*a theory*". (I'm not saying it's the case here, but in general, questions that are presented like this are often simply conjectures made up by the questioner.) The question would be much better received if rather than a vague reference it actually contained explicit quotations of this theory from at least semi-reputable sources. And yes, I do realize that that is exactly what you are asking for, but there must have been something that made you realize this theory already exists.

Comment: @ray, I redacted 80% of the question since it was an invitation to discussion, but I think the gist of it is the theory revolves around a move from nomadic to agrarian cultures.

Comment: @PeterTurner, yes (and thanks for the editing), It's only the use of "a theory" that I objected to (and I didn't down-vote).  If the questioner read about the theory elsewhere, I'd like to read it too.  And if the questioner developed the theory, it's still interesting (though perhaps not appropriate here).  But saying "a theory" is too vague.

Comment: @RayButterworth I don't know if I can claim any primacy, but this is something I have been thinking about for several years.  The root of the idea sprang up because I read an article severals years ago where the author was taking issue with the claim that Carthiginians practiced child sacrifice.  At the same time there was a lot of evidence that small children had been sacrificed and placed in burial jars. The root was linked to phoenician and canaanite practices.  So the question I pondered was whether a popular desire to end human sacrifice fueled the drive to christianity.